# C++ name space confusion - std:: vs :: vs no prefix on a call to tolower?

Tags: c++, namespaces, name-decoration

Why is this?

`transform(theWord.begin(), theWord.end(), theWord.begin(), std::tolower);`  - does not work
`transform(theWord.begin(), theWord.end(), theWord.begin(), tolower);`  - does not work

but

`transform(theWord.begin(), theWord.end(), theWord.begin(), ::tolower);`  - does work

theWord is a string. I am `using namespace std;`

Why does it work with the prefix `::` and not the with the `std::` or with nothing?

thanks for your help.

Comment: What header files are you including?

Comment: `#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>`

Answer (score 21):

`using namespace std;` instructs the compiler to search for undecorated names (ie, ones without `::`s) in `std` as well as the root namespace. Now, the [`tolower`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/tolower) you're looking at is part of the C library, and thus in the root namespace, which is always on the search path, but can also be explicitly referenced with `::tolower`.

There's also a [`std::tolower`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/locale/tolower/) however, which takes two parameters. When you have `using namespace std;` and attempt to use `tolower`, the compiler doesn't know which one you mean, and so it' becomes an error.

As such, you need to use `::tolower` to specify you want the one in the root namespace.

This, incidentally, is an example why `using namespace std;` can be a bad idea. There's enough random stuff in `std` (and C++0x adds more!) that it's quite likely that name collisions can occur. I would recommend you not use `using namespace std;`, and rather explicitly use, e.g. `using std::transform;` specifically.

Comment: So ::tolower tells the compiler look in the root name space, and std::tolower tells the compiler to look int the standard name space. Is that correct? And in this case I want the tolower from the root name space not the standard name space.

Comment: Right. Or you could stop using `using namespace std` and tolower would work properly :)

Comment: Technically, OP's ::tolower() only exists due to an implementation detail. To guarantee that C library's `tolower` is in the global namespace, `<ctype.h>` must be included rather than `<cctype>` (see `D.5[depr.c.headers]/2`)

Comment: so if one includes <cctype> and <locale> at the same time, std::tolower will be from which one?

Comment: @HayriUğurKoltuk Depends. Their definitions differ, so you'll have both.

Comment: The behavior of using `::tolower` is still unspecified, not only because `tolower` may not be in the global namespace as pointed out by Cubbi, but also because [one is usually not allowed to take the address of a standard library function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55687045/5376789).