# Why can not pass "std" prefix when giving Predicate parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, std

I have this code:

```
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string str("ABCD");
    std::all_of(str.begin(), str.end(), ::isxdigit);
    return 0;
}
```

`std::all_of` requires a Predicate as last argument. What I want to pass is `std::isxdigit`. When I pass it as `::isxdigit` it **works fine**, but when I pass it with **std**, like `std::isxdigit`, I get this **error**:

```
12:58: error: no matching function for call to 'all_of(std::basic_string<char>::iterator, std::basic_string<char>::iterator, <unresolved overloaded function type>)'
12:58: note: candidate is:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/algorithm:62:0,
                 from 6:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_algo.h:508:5: note: template<class _IIter, class _Predicate> bool std::all_of(_IIter, _IIter, _Predicate)
     all_of(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last, _Predicate __pred)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_algo.h:508:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
12:58: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter '_Predicate'
```

Why am I getting this error?
What is wrong with passing it with **std** prefix, if it DO is of std?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658767/c-name-space-confusion-std-vs-vs-no-prefix-on-a-call-to-tolower

Comment: [You can't take the address of a standard library function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55687045/5376789).

Comment: Reopen: The given duplicate for closing (https://stackoverflow.com/q/6658767/1741542) is about `using namespace std`. This is not the case here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make it working with `std::isxdigit` you should write something like:

```cpp
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string str("ABCD");
    std::all_of(str.begin(), str.end(), [](unsigned char c){ return std::isxdigit(c); });
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:10,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:10,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:10,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:10),source:'%23include+%3Ccctype%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstring%3E%0A%23include+%3Calgorithm%3E%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++std::string+str(%22ABCD%22)%3B%0A++++std::all_of(str.begin(),+str.end(),+%5B%5D(unsigned+char+c)%7B+return+std::isxdigit(c)%3B+%7D)%3B%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:49.85494633014216,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'0',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:14,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B11',selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50.145053669857845,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:2,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%232+with+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:50.145053669857845,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

Comment: It should also make the code faster - as otherwise isxdigit will be treated as function pointer inside the template which can result in slow unoptimizable code.